# Sidekiq fails to start when have I have admin model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, backgroundworker, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq to process the background jobs and it is not the first time I am using sidekiq.

Problem:

Sidekiq won't start if I have a devise model named admin.

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :registerable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

If I comment this "admin" model class then sidekiq would start normally works as expected. For now I am using sidekiq default configuration.

Error Backtrace:

```
bundle exec sidekiq
Admin is not a class
/home/ninja/workspace/howismyschool/app/models/admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/ninja/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/home/ninja/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/ninja/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/ninja/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/ninja/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/home/ninja/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/home/ninja/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/ninja/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/home/ninja/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/home/ninja/workspace/howismyschool/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/sidekiq-3.2.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:230:in `boot_system'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/sidekiq-3.2.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:49:in `run'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/gems/sidekiq-3.2.0/bin/sidekiq:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/ninja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@howismyschoolisdoing/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Application Environment:

- ruby 2.1.2
- rails 4.1.4
- Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

The error isn't related to sidekiq. `is not a class` exception most likely caused by naming collision(you defined constant `Admin` somewhere). Check your project for `Admin` constant and rename it.

How to reproduce an error in console(irb):

```
1.9.3-p448 :001 > A = 1
 => 1
1.9.3-p448 :002 > class A
1.9.3-p448 :003?> end
TypeError: A is not a class
```

Comment: Yes, this could be a problem. I have activeadmin installed in my application and this possibly seems to be the reason. When I comment the activeadmin completely from the application the sidekiq starts normally. I was looking into the activeadmin gem to find where this Admin constant has been defined but could not find so. So problem is with this Admin name collision, but where could not find that. for now I would rename my admin class.